# Getting exception while invoking jsp from a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have  a jsp. which calls a servlet on jsp load and display the results in same jsp as below.

Some.jsp

```
<html>

    <jsp:include page="/HelloWorld"/>

    <%Iterator itr;%>
<% List data= (List)request.getAttribute("results");
for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); )
{
%>


<TABLE align="center" cellpadding="15" border="1" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
                    <TR>
                        <TD align="center"><%=itr.next()%></TD>
                    </TR>

            </TABLE>

<%}%>


    </body>
</html>
```

in servlet i am storing results in request and using requestdispatcher to invoke the jsp as below.

```
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
              HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException,IOException{

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //some logic to populate list

        request.setAttribute("results", list);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Some.jsp").forward(request, response);


              }

}
```

But i am getting below exception while displaying results in jsp:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.clearBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:157)
```

Please help me..

Comment: You should write return after forwarding the request to the JSP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSP includes the servlet, which forwards to the JSP, which includes the servlet, which forwards to the JSP, which includes the servlet, which forwards to the JSP, which includes the servlet, which forwards to the JSP, which includes the servlet, which forwards to the JSP, which includes the servlet, which forwards to the JSP, which includes the servlet, which forwards to the JSP...

You have a serious design issue here. Adopt the MVC principles: all requests go to a servlet (Controller), which loads the Model, and dispatches to the appropriate JSP (View). A view should not include a servlet, and certainly not in a recursive way like this.

Comment: Hi Nizet, Thanks for your reply. in getRequestDispatcher method can i use another jsp to display results? Thanks!

Comment: Test it. But do you really want to keep using a crappy design? Why not do it the clean way?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nizet. instead of invoking servlet on jsp page load, can i directly call servlet and display results in a jsp? Please suggest me..

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested in my answer. Of course you can call your servlet directly without going through a JSP first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nizet. is it good practice to call a servlet directly? Please suggest me..

Comment: Yes, it is. It's at the core of the MVC design pattern. Read http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1999/jw-12-ssj-jspmvc.html for example. Spring MVC, Stripes, Struts (1 and 2), etc. are all frameworks that use this design pattern and follow this architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can not give servlet url pattern in jsp:iclude tag. The reason is, it doesnt know whther to call get method or ost method. You should give only jsp path.